# How can I restore app data after a failed uninstall?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, uninstall, restore

I'm not sure if the title for this question is correct, but I have an application installed at "C:\Program Files". I only have read access for "Program Files" and everything underneath. I forgot I only have read access and tried uninstalling the application, which failed. I now need to continue to use the application, but there is some functionality that I am missing. Specifically, I can still use the application, but I have to open it from its installation folder (the application no longer comes up when searching, nor can I pin it to the task bar). Should hopefully be quick fix. Thank you

Comment: Just create a new shortcut on your desktop to the application and pin that shortcut to your start menu.  However, it sounds like you should contact your system administrator, so they can reinstall your application.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your desktop and select `New > Shortcut`. Use `Browse` to select the application, then finish creating the shortcut. You should be able to use this to open up the app.
**Does it not work?**
You can always paste the file location into a Windows Key-R (Run) window and open it from there.